# Proof of divergence for complex number non-cauchy sequence

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers, cauchy-sequences

So, I trying to prove the following: "Show that a complex number sequence converges, iff, it is a Cauchy sequence".

Let $\{w_n\}$ be a complex number sequence. For every $\epsilon>0$,$\exists N=N(\epsilon)$, such that
$|w_n-w_m|\geq\epsilon,\forall n,m>N\Rightarrow \nexists w \in \mathscr{C}$/ $\lim_{n\to \infty}|w_n-w|=0 \therefore$ the sequence does not converge.

Is it correct? I'm not sure if the first statement implies the conclusion.

Comment: Well, if you proved anything, you proved implication, not equivalence.

Comment: Your proof makes no sense. First of all what you wrote is not the definition of non-Cauchy sequence by any means. In every place you must switch $\forall$ and $\exists$. A sequence is not Cauchy if $\exists\epsilon>0 \forall n_0\in\mathbb{N} \exists m,n\geq n_0: |w_m-w_n|\geq\epsilon$.

Comment: I got that $\forall m,n>N$ from a book. Why shouldn't it be valid for all m,n>N?

Comment: For the forward implication, if we find $N$ such that $|c_n -c| <\epsilon$ for $n>N$ then what can we say about $|c_n - c_m|$ for $n,m>N$

Comment: If it is valid for all $m,n$ then obviously the sequence is not Cauchy. But you are asking for much more than you really need. Even if for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$ there are some $m,n\geq N$ such that $|w_m-w_n|\geq\epsilon$ then the sequence is already not Cauchy. Only this way you can get all the sequences which are not Cauchy.

Comment: Have I written a tautology?